# How to use Turkish characters in xml?

Tags: xml, special-characters

I am using xml and have a problem with Turkish characters. Just like this

```
<Ürün></Ürün>...
```

I use str_replace for solution but it's not giving desired results.

What do I have to do?

Comment: What kind of problem? In what programming language?

Comment: no.when i wont to open xml file it gives an allert about character problem

Comment: Open it in what? What is the alert? Can you post the XML so we can see?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The above XML snippet is perfectly valid, as long as you've saved the XML with the correct character encoding. The default encoding for XML, if you don't specify a different one in the `<?xml` declaration, is UTF-8.

If you have saved the file containing `<Ürün>` in a different encoding to UTF-8 — presumably Windows code page 1254 Turkish — it will not parse as UTF-8, so either add a `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1254"?>` declaration or, much better and more portable, simply save it as UTF-8 instead. Use ‘Save as’ in your text editor and pick out that encoding.

(If your text editor does not afford you that option, or it insists on re-loading UTF-8 files in code page 1254, get a better text editor.)

Comment: Yes You are excatly right.it solve my question.thank you very much

Comment: &gt; Great, in that case, ...<br/>
I second that.  :)